# Exception Testing - Junit 4

Tags: java

i'm student that learning Junit, for my knowledge want to know what Exception testing is good for this code to run Junit test on "Empty", "null" and "fail"

```
public Profile(List<Grade> g) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: take a look at this api : http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for exception testing something like that

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void profileTest() {
    //your logic
}
```

Comment: ty, do you any resources for "list" that can help me?, i have resources for arraylist (For example new Arraylist<object>().get(0); this for empty list)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Explain me your target.

Comment: so on Junit Test, @Test(expected = illegalArugmentException.class) public void EmptyTest() {  use that profile method to call empty or null or fail Arugment }

Answer (score 1):

The clearest and most flexible way to test methods that throw exceptions in jUnit 4 is to use the `ExpectedException` rule. At the top of your test class:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();
```

This will set up `thrown` before each test, to expect no exception, and call it after each test to check whether an exception was thrown.

In an individual test:

```
@Test
public void applyDiscount_throws_exception_when_customer_is_non_member() {

    Order order = new Order(newNonMemberCustomer());

    thrown.expect(DiscountEligibilityException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("Cannot apply discount to non-member");

    order.applyDiscount(DISCOUNT_CODE);

}
```

This will pass when an exception is thrown that matches the expectations. If no exception is thrown, or an exception is thrown doesn't match expectations, it will fail with a useful description of the reason.

---

Prior to `ExpectedException`, there was the `@Test(expected = ExceptionType.class)` form, which was easy to miss visually, and limited in how much validation you could do.

---

There is also the do-it-yourself way:

```
 @Test
 public void applyDiscount_throws_exception_when_customer_is_non_member() {
      Order order = new Order(newNonMemberCustomer());
      try {
           order.applyDiscount(DISCOUNT_CODE);
           fail("Expected an exception");
      } catch(DiscountEligibilityException e) {
           assertThat(e.getMessage(), is("Cannot apply discount to non-member");
      }
 }
```

... but `ExpectedException` is easier, clearer, more standard, and powerful.